# Adding random values in column depending on other columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I have a dataframe with the Columns "OfferID", "SiteID" and "CatgeoryID" which should represent an online ad on a website. I then want to add a new Column called "NPS" for the net promoter score. The values should be given randomly between 1 and 10 but where the OfferID, the SideID and the CatgeoryID are the same, they need to have the same value for the NPS. I thought of using a dictionary where the NPS is the key and the pairs of different IDs are the values but I haven't found a good way to do this.

Are there any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.
Alina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be first to remove all duplicates ; you can do this using :

```
uniques = df[['OfferID', 'SideID', 'CategoryID']].drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

Afterwards, you can do something like this (note that your random values are not uniques) :

```
uniques['NPS'] = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in uniques.index]
```

And then :

```
df = df.merge(uniques, on=['OfferID', 'SideID', 'CategoryID'], how='left')
```